# sql syntax error (incorrect syntax near =)

Tags: sql

Hello I am having a problem here.
I wanted to read subjectname from a dynamic table name and the save it to a variable.
but i am getting an error

```
DECLARE @retval varchar(200)   
DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @academicYear varchar(200) = '20212022';
Declare @subjectId varchar(200) = '202041962';

DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(50)   = 'abc' + CAST(@academicyear As varchar)
DECLARE @CONDITION NVARCHAR(128)
SET @CONDITION = 'WHERE [subjectid] = 202041962'

SELECT @sSQL = N'SELECT @retvalOUT = [subjectname] FROM ' + @tablename + @CONDITION;  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@retvalOUT varchar OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, @ParmDefinition, @retvalOUT=@retval OUTPUT;

SELECT @retval;
```

Comment: In which line do you get the eror? Please add the tag for the dbms do you use?

Comment: my table name should be abc20212022.
so i want to select subjectname from the table where subjectid is202041962 and set it in a variable

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: What is the value of @sSQL that you are trying to execute? I suspect a missing space between the tablename and the WHERE. Also you may have missing quotes around the subjectid-value

Comment: About `CAST(... AS varchar)`: When n isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. If n isn't specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql#remarks)

Answer (score 1):

If you actually *looked* at the value of `@sSQL` eg by `print`ing it, you'll note it contains `FROM abc20212022WHERE`, therefore,

1. you are not delimiting your table names - use `quotename()`
2. you need a *space* between your table name and the `where`
3. you should always specify a *length* for a *varchar* value (you don't need to *cast* a variable when concatenating two strings but you should be *consistent* with your use of [n]varchar)
4. using *concat* to concatenate strings is easier and safer